# Plotting time series data with with 30sec break point and color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new in python programming. I can simply plot the input data shown in the figure with my code but how can I plot the time series data as mention in the figure. Any code and suggestions will be thankful.
[image]

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y_values = [5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1] 
x_values = np.arange(30, 331, 30)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_values,y_values,"-x") 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is a way to draw a series of rectangular shapes, we used a general method and used horizontal bar charts. We added a list for the values in the bar chart and stacked the values. Class label names and class titles are now supported as annotations. You can try various other parameters.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = [5]*11
y_values = [5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1] 
x_values = np.arange(30, 331, 30)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,1))
ax.barh(y=0, height=1.0, edgecolor='k', width=y[0], label='Time Interval')
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y_values[i] == 5:
        color = 'y'
    else:
        color = 'm'
    ax.barh(y=0, left=sum(y[:i]), height=1.0, width=y[i], color=color, edgecolor='k', label='Time Interval')

for s in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    ax.spines[s].set_visible(False)

for i,(p,t) in enumerate(zip(y, y_values)):
    ax.text(y=0.6, x=2.5+p*i, s=str(t))

ax.text(-0.08, 1, 'Class', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_ylabel('Time Interval', rotation=0, labelpad=40, loc='center')
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y_values = ['class', 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1]
x_values = np.arange(30, 331, 30)
x_values = np.concatenate((['Time'],x_values))

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'class': y_values, 'Time': x_values})
colors = {5: 'gold', 1: 'darkviolet'}
df['colors'] = df['class'].map(colors)
df['colors'].fillna('white', inplace=True)
df['Time'].iloc[1:] = ''
print(df)

fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
data = df.T.values
colors = [data[2].tolist()]
table = ax.table(cellText=[data[1].tolist()], colLabels=data[0].tolist(),loc="center", cellColours=colors)
table.set_fontsize(14)

for i in range(len(data[0])):
    table[0, i].visible_edges = ''

table[1, 0].visible_edges = ''
table.scale(1.5, 1.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]